# Binding the Checked Property of a CheckBox within a TemplateItem

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, checkbox, templatefield

For the life of me I cannot bind the Checked property of a CheckBox control within a TemplateField (declaritively).

I have tried:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="deactivated" runat="server" checked="<%#Eval("Deactivated")%>"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

and

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="deactivated" runat="server" checked="<%#Eval(Container.DataItem, "Deactivated")%>"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>      
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I keep seeing a warning stating:

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from it's string representation' 'for the 'Checked' property

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may be because of the double quotes you've used. Try:

```
checked= '<%# Eval("Deactivated") %>'
```

Comment: You are right. I won't work with the double quotes as outer quotes

Comment: Do you know why single quotes are required?

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes around the property value:

`<asp:CheckBox ID="deactivated" runat="server" checked='<%#Eval("Deactivated")%>'></asp:CheckBox>`

Answer (score 1):

It's best to handle this via code-behind in the control's rowdatabound event (assuming it's a gridview).

```
if (e.Row.RowType == RowType.DataRow)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) GridView1.FindControl("deactivated");
    chk.Checked = true;
}
```

Note: The abv code may contain errors ...

OR,

Retrieve the data in such a manner that that particular field the checkbox is trying to bind to should be a field of type bit (i.e. it can either have 1 or 0).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but here's what I had to do in VS2013, `System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

```
<asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="50" HeaderText="Is Verified">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkVerified" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkVerified_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%#DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem,"IsVerified").ToString()=="0"%>' />

                        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

because my property was not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Eval is for evaluating expressions.

Try Bind.

```
checked='<%#Bind("Deactivated")%>'
```